# Force linking a static library into a shared one with Libtool

Tags: static, shared, autotools, libtool

I have a library (*libfoo*) that is compiled **using libtool** into two objects: libfoo.a and libfoo.so.

I have to create, **using libtool** also, another library (*libbar*) that will be a single shared library (libbar.so) containing all libfoo's code.

In order to do this, I have to force *libbar* to link against **libfoo.a**, and not libfoo.so.

I am in an **autotools** environment, so I have to solve this using standard *configure.in* or *Makefile.am* rules.

I tried several things, like in configure.in :

```
LDFLAGS="$LDFLAGS "-Wl,-Bstatic -lfoo -Wl,-Bdynamic"
```

That always results in the -Wl flags on the linking line; but -lfoo has disappeared and has been placed in an absolute-path form (*/opt/foo/lib/libfoo.so*) at the beginning of it.

I also tried:

```
LDFLAGS="$LDFLAGS "-L/opt/foo/lib libfoo.a"
```

or in Makefile.am:

```
libbar_la_LDADD = -Wl,-Bstatic -lfoo -Wl,-Bdynamic
```

and

```
libbar_la_LTLIBRARIES = libfoo.a
```

etc etc (with many, many variants !)

But I think that definitely I do not have knowledge enough of Autotools/Libtool to solve this alone. I have not been able to find information on the Net about it, always slightly different issues.

Answer (score 7):

You could probably use a [convenience library](http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Libtool-Convenience-Libraries.html). Convenience libraries are intermediate static libraries which are not installed. You could use the prefix `noinst` to build one.

```
noinst_LTLIBRARIES = libfoo_impl.la

lib_LTLIBRARIES = libfoo.la libbar.la
libfoo_la_LIBADD = libfoo_impl.la
libbar_la_LIBADD = libfoo_impl.la
```

Comment: This is the proper solution. Just for the sake of completeness, the convenience libraries are compiled as *static* regardless of what configure flags were given. At least on Unix.

Answer (score 5):

The standard way would be to build `libfoo` with `--disable-shared`.  Whether to link statically or dynamically is a decision for the user to make, so there's really no way to force it as a package maintainer, but you could set the configury of `libbar` to fail if `libfoo.so` is present (I'm not sure of a clean way to do that, and believe it would be a bad idea since it really is a choice for the user.)  I think the best bet is to have the user build `libfoo` with `--disable-shared`, but you can force that choice by specifying static libraries only in libfoo/configure.ac:

```
LT_INIT([disable-shared])
```

Note that if you do that, it will not be possible to build `libfoo` as a shared library.  Perhaps that is what you want.

Comment: howd you do it without libtool?